# how to add two mutable array? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, nsarray

In my app I want to implement pull down to refresh. So when scroll view scroll down its load more data. Now first time when page loads I save data in *videoArray* array, and when scroll down I got data in *videoArray2* array so how can I add value of *videoArray2* to *videoArray*? both are nsmuttablearray.

Here is my code:

```
var videoArray : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var videoArray2 : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
```

First time I stored value in this array

```
self.videoArray = (response.result.value)?.valueForKey("posts") as! NSMutableArray
```

Second time I stored value in this array

```
self.videoArray2 = (response.result.value)?.valueForKey("posts") as! NSMutableArray
```

This is how I tried to append

```
for enumerator in self.videoArray2
{
    self.videoArray.addObject(enumerator)
}
```

but its throwing error like

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

So how can I solve this?

Comment: Do not use `NSMutableArray` – use Swift's native array type instead. You can always bridge an `NSArray` that you receive from objc back to a native Swift array via conditional downcasting.

Comment: pure swift is better option and than just use `appendContentsOf` method ... thats all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let videoArray = (response.result.value)?.valueForKey("posts") as! NSArray
self.videoArray = NSMutableArray(array:videoArray)
```

and the same for the second array

Answer (score 5):

It is as simple as this in Swift way

```
var array : [AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()
var array1 : [AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()
//Add array like this
array.appendContentsOf(array1)
```

OR like this as declared by you

```
var videoArray : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var videoArray2 : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
//Add like this
videoArray.addObjectsFromArray(videoArray2 as [AnyObject])
```

OR

```
videoArray2.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock { (data, index, finished) in
        self.videoArray.addObject(data)
    }
```

Comment: If you're going to use array declared in Swift file on Obj-C file, you may have to use NSMutableArray. Nice answer, @Amit. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**// (response.result.value)?.valueForKey("posts") returning the NSArray so you have to take it in an array object then you can transfer all objects to your mutablearray**

```
let array = (response.result.value)?.valueForKey("posts") as! NSMutableArray
self.videoArray = NSMutableArray(array:array)
```

**// Added objects from videoArray2 to videoArray**

```
self.videoArray.addObjectsFromArray(self.videoArray2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace this line code 

self.videoArray = (response.result.value)?.valueForKey("posts") as! NSMutableArray

With 

let vidArray = response.result.value)?.valueForKey("posts") as! NSArray;
self.videoArray = vidArray.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray


First Line of code get the data from server as NSArray and later second line creates a mutable copy of that array.

Now Code below Run as expected.
for enumerator in self.videoArray2
{
    self.videoArray.addObject(enumerator)
}

Now you can add objects to the mutable copy of the videoArray.
```